# AutoHotkey don't exit the script

Tags: autohotkey

In autohotkey, the code below would let me press alt+1 may times and without exiting the script.

```
!1::
{
  Send abcd
  Return
}
```

But how do you accomplish the same result with the code below, using WinWaitActive. Can't figure out how to prevent it from exiting the script.

```
  WinWaitActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
  Send abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [#Persistent](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_Persistent.htm)

```
#Persistent
WinWaitActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
Send abcd
```